# Multithreading in such a way that I am able to accept multiple clients in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, client-side-validation

I am expected to write a server that can handle multiple clients in Python, and so far I am able to deal with one connection(from a client)but I really don't know how to extend my program to handle multiple clients. I tried looking at Twisted, but couldn't really grasp it.

Any recommendations, or sample code that can help me understand how to handle multiple clients? Ideally, I should be able to have multiple clients connected to the server, and based on the input they pass once they are connected, I should be able to do all sort of fascinating things by parsing their input, etc.

I really look forward to your responses, and thank you in advance for your time. I'm a long time lurker.

P.S
I already looked at most other multithreading examples of Python, they didn't quite honestly help.

Thanks.

Comment: You will get a better response to your question if you post the single threaded code that you have already implemented.

Comment: Maybe...persevere with twisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SocketServer with the ThreadingMixIn so each client connection is handled on a separate thread.

Here's a starting point for you.

```
import SocketServer

PORT = 5000

class Server(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    daemon_threads = True

class Handler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        # TODO: handle this client
        # this sample acts as an echo server
        while True:
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            self.request.sendall(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = Server(('', PORT), Handler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Hi FogleBird, so in that todo area, everytime a client try to run it, that will run? How can I keep track of my clients? suppose I have 10 clients connected, and I want to toggle with the first two, how would I go by doing that?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Toggle in what fashion? Could you give an example with some pseudocode? You might be better off having the clients send some short command which your server responds to, to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the python module [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html).

If you use Google to search for network programming (not especially Python network programming) and client server programming, you'll find a lot of useful resources that explain things. I recommend [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Also, I'd recommend to keep away from asynchronous network programming, until you grasp the basics.

Comment: Ive been googling all day, and I have yet to find a comprehensive example that elaborates upon multiple clients, and one server